# Different display of components in my phone screen

Tags: java, android, layout

i have a problem with android studio on my layout the items display as closed to each other but on my phone there is a big space like the image, how can i solve it and reduce the space and show it as real as in my phone ?!
[see the image here](http://s1.postimg.org/m6toce5an/000.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you are using a normal phone for your emulator and you are using a tablet in real, so inside Android Studio, when working with an xml layout file, change your device to something with a large screen/resolution, maybe Nexus 7 or Nexus 10 tablets..

Comment: i mean the android studio itself show my items close to each other but on the emulator or the phone there is a big space, i want my android studio to show me the real dimensions and spaces, nad yes my phone is tablet and the emulator is samsung galaxy s4

Comment: just change the device in android studio as in this picture, http://oi60.tinypic.com/c0uf6.jpg

Comment: ok , which is the best layout to set items in accurate position ?

Comment: There's no best layout that works for all, you have to set the layouts according to the devices you are targetting, check your real device's resolution & screen size, and set it accordingly in android studio. If you have a 7 inch tablet, choose Nexus 7, or you can click Preview All Screen sizes so that you get an idea how it looks on different screen sizes and resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the resolution and display size of your emulator matches your phone, that should give you a more accurate representation.

Comment: i mean the android studio itself show my items close to each other but on the emulator or the phone there is a big space, i want my android studio to show me the real dimensions and spaces